# Changing AngularJS Property changes value of an HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a **base.html** page with code

```html
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="MyController">
<body style="background-color: [[ BackgroundPrimaryColor ]]">
.
.
.
{{ block content }}
{{ endblock }}
.
.
.
</body>
<script>
// Creating an AngularJS Module for our AngularJS Application
var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);

// Changing syntax for AngularJS Expression
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

// Defining AngularJS Controller for our AngularJS Application
app.controller("MyController",function($scope){
    // Defining AngularJS Application Property to specify Mode of the Website
    $scope.DarkMode=false;

    // Defining function to change Mode of the Website
    $scope.changeDarkLightMode=function(){
        // Changing other values
        if ($scope.DarkMode){
            $scope.BackgroundPrimaryColor="black";
        }
        else{
            $scope.BackgroundPrimaryColor="white";
        }

        // Changing value of the property DarkMode
        $scope.DarkMode=!$scope.DarkMode;

    };
    
    // Calling changeDarkLightMode() whenever page loads
    $scope.changeDarkLightMode();

});
</script>
</html>
```

I have another page by name **contact me.html** with code

```html
{{ block content }}
<body onload="onLoad()">
.
.
.
</body>
<script>
function onLoad(){
 document.getElementsbyTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style","background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: scroll;background-image: url({% static 'Contact_Me_Image.png' %});background-size:cover;background-position: 0% 20%;");}
</script>
{{ endblock }}
```

So the **contact me.html** page forms a part of the **base.html**.

In **contact me.html** page, I'm setting the `style` attribute of the `body` from the `<script>` tag, so that `body` changes from

```html
<body style="background-color: [[ BackgroundPrimaryColor ]]">
...
</body>
```

to

```html
<body style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: scroll;background-image: url({% static 'Contact_Me_Image.png' %});background-size:cover;background-position: 0% 20%;">
...
</body>
```

Everything works fine till I change the value of the AngularJS Property `BackgroundPrimaryColor`.
As soon as I change the value of the AngularJS Property `BackgroundPrimaryColor`, `body` again changes from

```html
<body style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: scroll;background-image: url({% static 'Contact_Me_Image.png' %});background-size:cover;background-position: 0% 20%;">
...
</body>
```

to

```html
<body style="background-color: [[ BackgroundPrimaryColor ]]">
...
</body>
```

So can anyone tell why changing value of the AngularJS Property `BackgroundPrimaryColor` changes the value of the `style` attribute of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

please remove custom  **"[["** interpolate, this thing can achievable by using **"{{"** default tag

```
<body style="background-color: {{BackgroundPrimaryColor}}">
...
</body>
```

and in controller use this

```
app.controller("MyController",function($scope){

$scope.BackgroundPrimaryColor="#FFF";

$scope.init=function(){
    $scope.BackgroundPrimaryColor="red";
}

$scope.init();

});
```

Comment: Actually I'm using Django at backend, so only I'm not using the default "{{" tags of AngularJS.
And changing the Controller code didn't solved my problem.